# (Java Minecraft 1.14) how to access a written book's contents?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently modifying a datapack that changes the skullowner (tag) of a `player_head` to a written book's title to get that player's head skin.

> `execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:player_head"}}] at @s if entity    @e[type=item,limit=1,distance=0.1..0.3,sort=nearest,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:written_book"}}] run`
>
> `data modify entity @s Item.tag.SkullOwner set from entity    @e[type=item,limit=1,distance=0.1..0.3,sort=nearest,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:written_book"}}] Item.tag.title`

I tried to change it to `Item.tag.pages[0]`, and it did display the first page's contents, but it was encased. Let's say I typed `Notch` in the first page then signed the book. When I tried to copy it as a `player_head`'s skullowner tag it turned into `{text:Notch}`.

But when I change `Item.tag.title` to `Item.tag.pages[0].text` to get the text in the first page, it doesn't work.

My main goal is to change the `player_head.skullowner.id` from the book's first page and `player_head.skullowner.properties.textures[0].value` from the second page in order to be able to change the head into a custom head such as ones found in [custom head websites](https://freshcoal.com/maincollection).

The original datapack can be found [here](https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/headchanger-easily-change-player-heads-in-1-14/).

Answer (score 1):

Book texts are stored as JSON. There is currently no way in Minecraft to properly handle existing JSON or do anything else with strings, apart from directly copying or checking for equality.